# How is the IP Application layer implemented?

Tags: ip, protocols

I am struggling to describe simply what the IP Application layer actually “is”. Some of my terminology may be “not quite right”, so I am happy to be corrected on my terminology as well. Is the application layer a “thing”? Or is it more “conceptual” than that? Is the Application layer on a particular node solely that collection of protocols (such as FTP, POP3, HTTP) that an application needs to adhere to if it is to successfully communicate with another remote application?

Conversely, if I write a program that does not strictly conform to an application protocol (say FTP) then there is nothing in the local “application layer” that will “stop” my attempt to communicate to the remote end using an invalid command? Whereas, if the remote end does conform to the application protocol, then it will reject or ignore my invalid communication attempt?

Or again, I could define my own protocol (not necessary as I guess all scenarios are already covered), and as long as my protocol was “robust and consistent” I could use it to communicate between two remote applications and everything would work? Or, is the Application layer a “thing” separate from the protocols?

Answer (score 0):

The application layer is everything that's inside the application - that is, not within the IP stack (which covers network and transport layers).

If you want your application to communicate with an FTP server it needs to be able to speak FTP in order to work. If you write your own client-server protocol you can do whatever you want.

The network layers are there to make your life easier and to make applications compatible with each other. You can use or not use whatever you seem fit.

Answer (score 0):

“An application needs to communicate with another application on a remote system. Any communication can be thought of as the exchange of messages and data between two partners. There are rules (protocols) that define for an application: what commands are available, the sequence that they can be exchanged between partners and any limitations on the data exchanged. For example: communication with an HTTP server uses commands: GET, POST and PUT (and others), whereas communication with an SMTP (mail) server uses: MAIL, RCPT and DATA, and similarly for other protocols. There are different protocols depending on the nature of the communication e.g. text message transfer, file transfer or video streaming. Any commands that are sent by either partner that do not obey those protocol rules is either: not delivered to, ignored or rejected by the remote application. Nothing prohibits application partners using their “own” communication protocol – for example Skype developed an uses its own protocol. However, there are standard protocols that handle most conceivable communication needs, so developing a new protocol may be unnecessary. If an application uses a “private” protocol its communication will be limited to remote applications that support the same private protocol. In addition to protocols, in a practical, real-world, system there are programming libraries (Programming interfaces) that enable the end-user application to request and participate in this communication. It is the end-user application’s responsibility to interact (send and receive data and parameters) with the (local programming) interface and the comms system’s responsibility to process those requests and deliver the data. In simplistic terms, one data transmission starts at one application and ends at another. However, IP provides other applications, such as DNS, that are used to set up connections, but the operation of these is not visible at the end-user application level. In summary, the collection of protocols and the programming interfaces available and used by an end-user application is the application layer on a system.”